# SQL SELECT Query Issues

Tags: sql, select

I am having an issue with my SELECT query. I am trying to find items that do not start with "50700" and have an enabled flag of 1, are in category 4 and sub category 4. Below is the query i have but it is not returning any results when i know there are some. Please note TBL1.FIELD1 = ITM_ID, TBL1.FIELD2 = ENABLED, TBL2.FIELD1 = CAT_ID, TBL2.FIELD2 = SUBCAT_ID.

```
SELECT DB_NAME.dbo.TBL1.FIELD1 
 , DB_NAME.dbo.TBL1.FIELD2 
 , DB_NAME.dbo.TBL2.FIELD1 
 , DB_NAME.dbo.TBL2.FIELD2
FROM DB_NAME.dbo.TBL1 
   , DB_NAME.dbo.TBL2
WHERE DB_NAME.dbo.TBL1.FIELD1 NOT LIKE '50700%' 
  AND DB_NAME.dbo.TBL1.FIELD2 = 1 
  AND DB_NAME.dbo.TBL2.FIELD1 = 4 
  AND DB_NAME.dbo.TBL2.FIELD2 = 4
```

Comment: I believe the query.  You have no matches.

Comment: Is `TBL1.FIELD1` of numeric type or character type?  If the former, do you expect a consistent number of total digits?

Comment: [Here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5b5b4/2/0) of your query returning matches where the data actually match.

Comment: I'm missing the Join between the two tables in your query. If you split your query into a separate query for each table, at least one of those will show an empty resultset.

Comment: @StefanDorner good approach.  Show us a record in tbl1 that has field1 not like '50700%' with field2=1 and one in tbl2 with field1 and field2 equal to 4.  using a cross join 0*1 = 0.  1*0=0.  so the only way you get no records, is if tbl1 or table2 have no records matching your result!

Answer (score 0):

You can break the query into different subqueries for debug purpose, this way you can figure out which "AND" condition is not working.

For Example:
Firstly I guess you should try a simple query on TBL1.FIELD1 with the simple query :

```
select TBL1.FIELD1 from DB_NAME.dbo.TBL1 where DB_NAME.dbo.TBL1.FIELD1  NOT LIKE '50700' ;(*if TBL1.FIELD1 is of String type, else go for TBL1.FIELD1 != 50700 * )
```

Then if you get results ,try to do "AND" with the TBL1.FIELD2 condition.

```
select TBL1.FIELD1 
from DB_NAME.dbo.TBL1
where DB_NAME.dbo.TBL1.FIELD1 NOT LIKE '50700' 
and DB_NAME.dbo.TBL1.FIELD2 =4 ;
```

This way you can proceed further and debug the query. Hope it helps :)